# Why my macro is fragile in a title? Can I make it more solid?

Tags: macros, fragile

The follwoing code stops the compilation even if the output is the good one if the message are ignored.

Why my macro is fragile? Can I make here more solid ?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\makeatletter
    \def\txtIf{\@ifstar\tnsalgo@txtIf@star\tnsalgo@txtIf@no@star}
    \def\tnsalgo@txtIf@no@star{\textbf{Si}}
    \def\tnsalgo@txtIf@star{\texttt{Si}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Conditional: \protect\txtIf{}} % <-- OK

\subsubsection{Conditional: \txtIf{}}         % <-- KO

\end{document}
```

Log :

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.9.12)  12 SEP 2020 13:22
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**pdftex-titel-pb.tex
(./pdftex-titel-pb.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-09-06>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count168
\c@section=\count169
\c@subsection=\count170
\c@subsubsection=\count171
\c@paragraph=\count172
\c@subparagraph=\count173
\c@figure=\count174
\c@table=\count175
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2020-09-11 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count176
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box45
)
(./pdftex-titel-pb.aux)
\openout1 = `pdftex-titel-pb.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.

./pdftex-titel-pb.tex:13: Argument of \@sect has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.13 \subsubsection{Conditional: \txtIf{}}
                                          
? 
Runaway argument?
{\normalfont \normalsize \bfseries }{\@firstoftwo {\tnsalgo@txtIf@star \ETC.
./pdftex-titel-pb.tex:13: Paragraph ended before \@sect was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.13 \subsubsection{Conditional: \txtIf{}}
                                          
? 
[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./pdftex-titel-pb.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 378 strings out of 480876
 6653 string characters out of 5907597
 243537 words of memory out of 5000000
 16086 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 535693 words of font info for 31 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 24i,4n,25p,181b,114s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public
/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/
amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb>
Output written on pdftex-titel-pb.pdf (1 page, 17436 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 16 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 10 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an in-depth discussion of what makes a command "robust" or "fragile", see [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/5001)

In addition to `\protect`ing a fragile command, as you do in `\subsubsection{Conditional: \protect\txtIf{}}`, there are (at least) two ways you can succeed in placing the command in question in the argument of a "moving" command:

- Make the command robust from the outset, by defining with `\DeclareRobustCommand` instead of with either `\def` or `\newcommand`.
- Make the command robust after it's been created, by loading the `etoolbox` package and executing

  ```
  \robustify{\fragilecommand}
  ```

  E.g., `\robustify{\txtIf}`.

Comment: The LaTeX kernel defines, since 2015, `\MakeRobust`, which has the same effect as defining the command with `\DeclareRobustCommand` (as long as it was defined with `\newcommand`, of course, otherwise it just adds the usual `\protect\command␣` mechanism)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik - Thanks. I suppose I had a good reason for writing "there are (at least) two ways". :-) There's also `\protected\def`, `\protected@edef`, and problably a few others. Real quick: does `\MakeRobust` work on an already-existing command (à la `\robustify`) or on new commands as well?

Comment: I would use \NewDocumentCommand from the xparse package to define the command,  commands defined with it are always robust (and xparse makes it easier to define a starred variant).

Comment: @Mico I know, I just had to advertise it, since I recently made some changes to make it _exactly_ like `\DeclareRobustCommand` ;-) (and note that `\protected@edef` is entirely different from `\protected\edef`).  Yes, `\MakeRobust` is quite similar to `\robustify`, except that it applies LaTeX2e's `\protect` mechanism to the macro, while `etoolbox` applies e-TeX's `\protected`.  But the macro has to be already defined for it to work.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik you should write an article about it :-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - I've made the answer a community wiki; please feel free to modify or add to it as you see fit.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik - I've made the answer a community wiki; please feel free to modify or add to it as you see fit.